# Show/hide div based on selected option value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder why it isn't working.

Here is my JS:

```
$("#cat-code").change(function(){
  var value = $("#cat-code option:selected").val();
  if (value == "10400000"){
    $("#div1").show();
    $("#div2").hide();
  }
});
```

Select Tag:

```
<select class="cat-code" id="cat-code" name="project_procurement_management_plan[items_attributes][0][category_id]">
  <option value="1">10400000</option>
  <option value="2">10401000</option>
</select>
```

Divs to show or hide:

```
<div class="div1">hi</div>
<div class="div2">hello</div>
```

Any workarounds will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: replace class with id in div tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've specifically set the values to 1 and 2, so that's probably what they are then:

```
$("#cat-code").change(function(){
  var value = this.value;
  if (value == "1"){
    $(".div1").show();
    $(".div2").hide();
  }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9uQmU/3/)

The options text will only be used as the selects value if the option does not have a value, and to get the selected value all you need is `this.value` inside the handler for the select.

Comment: Hi thanks. Sorry im about to collapse just right now for not sleeping. I accidentally interchanged classes to ids and so on. Will accept this answer after 9 mins

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your JS is reference to DOM objects with IDs, but your HTML has classes.

Try this JS instead:

```
$(".div1").show();
$(".div2").hide();
```